# Socket ports are not matching listening ports

Tags: sockets, port, haxe

I am setting up a simple server using sys.net.Socket (cpp, linux).

The server is bound like this:

```
hostSocket.bind(new Host("0.0.0.0"), 20301);
```

And I connect to the server like this:

```
clientSocket.connect(new Host("localhost"), 20301);
```

If the ports do not match, the connection won't work, so that works as expected.
However, when I "accept" the connection on the server side, and want to print information about the client, I get a random port whenever a new connection is incoming, just never 20301:

```
var connectedClient : Socket = hostSocket.accept();

trace("Incoming connection from " + connectedClient.peer().host.toString() 
      + " on port " + connectedClient.peer().port);
```

Now I get results like this:

> Incoming connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 50977
>
> Incoming connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 50978
>
> Incoming connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 50979

What is going on here? Why is the displayed port not 20301?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both server and client sockets need to bind to some local address (ip,port) for a connection to happen.

The client simply binds to a local *free* port, and will very likely change a lot, depending on all other connections happening on your machine.

Finally, Haxe sockets are (sometimes indirectly) wrappers over POSIX sockets; the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/connect.html) for `connect()` says:

> If the socket has not already been bound to a local address, `connect()` shall bind it to an address which, ..., is an unused local address.

Comment: Ah, I see. I just assumed that the same port would be used on both ends, but I can see how this approach makes more sense.